# Can socket in SCM_RIGHTS protocol type send data even file description is -1

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Now I use SCM_RIGHTS protocol to send fd (file description). But sometimes my fd will get -1 for some reason. And I want tell receiver that sender got wronge even at this time.
But when I use "sendmsg" will got: Failed to send message: Bad file descriptor
My sender code below:

```
int32_t SendFrame(const char *sockPath, char *sendFrameInfo, uint32_t sendFrameInfoLen,
                  int32_t inFd) {
    int SockFd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_un peer;

    /* Create name. */
    peer.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(peer.sun_path, sockPath);
    int ret = connect(SockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    struct msghdr msg = {0};
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg;
    char buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    struct iovec io = {.iov_base = (void *)sendFrameInfo, .iov_len = sendFrameInfoLen};

    msg.msg_iov = &io;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = buf;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(buf);

    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
    cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(int));

    memcpy((int *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg), &inFd, sizeof(int));

    if (sendmsg(SockFd, &msg, 0) < 0) {
        printf("SendFrame(%s) Failed to send message: %s", sockPath, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

My receiver code below:

```
int32_t recvFrame(char *buf, int32_t fd, uint32_t timeout_ms, uint32_t bufsize) {
    struct msghdr msg = {0};
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg;

    char msg_control[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];
    memset(msg_control, '\0', sizeof(msg_control));
    
    struct iovec io = { .iov_base = &buf, .iov_len = bufsize };

    msg.msg_iov = &io;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = msg_control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(msg_control);

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = timeout_ms / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000;

    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    ssize_t len = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);
    if (len < 0) {
        perror("Failed to receive message");
        return -errno;
    }

    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);

    int new fd = *((int32_t *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg));
    return 0;
}
```

Now I can use So how can I use "msg_iov" to send other message. So I want receive message event sender's fd is -1 then I can check "msg_iov" what is happened.
Thanks!

BR/Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only pass valid file descriptors, and -1 is never a valid file descriptor (because it is returned when an error occurs).

What I would recommend, is to include a special byte (char) in the message, describing the error – for example, as the very first char in the message.  It is zero if a file descriptor is passed, and nonzero if an error occurs (the value describing the error).  This way, the payload data is never of zero length, which makes it much easier to detect socket close before sending any data. (Zero-length reads/receives normally indicate end-of-input, you see.)

Because `errno` values do not necessarily match across machines, you should translate the special byte values to errno codes and vice versa.

Alternatively, if the message has no other data, you could send the error message as a string, including the `'\0'` end-of-string mark at end; with just a `'\0'` as the data payload when a file descriptor is passed.

Comment: The part about translating errno codes is unnecessary, you can't send SCM_RIGHTS to a different machine.